# DJANGO: How can I create a custom User with a OneToOne relationship to Person

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have a custom user model, I would like my CustomUser model to have a OneToOne relationship with the Person model; Since I want to first register persons and then create a username for them, since not all registered people need to have a username.

I have tried the code shown below; but what I get is the following error:

```
Cannot assign "1": "CustomUser.dni" must be a "Person" instance.
```

But, the ID number is already registered in the Person table

P.S. If anyone has a better suggestion for getting people to register first and then create a username for them when strictly necessary, I'd really appreciate it.

***`models.py`***

```
    from .managers import CustomUserManager
    
# MODEL PERSON
    class Person(models.Model):
        dni = models.CharField('Número de DNI', max_length=8, unique=True)
...
    
# MODEL CUSTOMUSER
    class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        dni = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
        email = models.EmailField('Correo electrónico', max_length=355, unique=True)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
        objects = CustomUserManager()
    
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'dni'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
...
```

***`managers.py`***

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, dni, email, password=None):
        if not dni:
            raise ValueError('Debe ingresar el número de DNI.')
        
        person = self.model(
            dni=dni,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        person.set_password(password)
        person.save(using=self._db)
        return person

    def create_superuser(self, dni, email, password=None):
        person = self.create_user(
            dni, 
            password=password,
            email=email,
        )
        person.is_admin = True
        person.is_superuser = True
        person.save(using=self._db)
        return person
```

***settings.py***

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

***views.py***

```
from accounts.forms import RegisterForm

class RegisterView(View):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'accounts/register.html'
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Cuenta creada para exitosamente.')
        
            return redirect(to='/')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

1. I want to register a person in the Person table.
2. After creating the person, you should only be able to create their username and password, from the administration site; that is, an external person cannot register on the site, because the site will have many people in the database, but only some of them will be users of the system.

I hope this image helps clarify the idea.

[Process flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57vla.jpg)

Comment: Have you customised the user registration form at all? Can you describe your user registration workflow and any view code associated to that?

Comment: @Swift , Thanks for your answer, Yes,  I have completely customized the user model.  I have added the view and I have described the process a bit, I also uploaded an image.

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking to do is subclass the django registration form. Then you can change the fields that are required.

I believe the password field would be required by default so a NULL value would not be valid. However, you could quite easily set the password as a randomly generated UUID and then manually change it in the admin panel.